# Vagrant can't find plugins after downgrading to 1.8.4 on Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

After learning that the latest version of Vagrant that I had installed(1.9.x) doesn't work quite well with the vagrant box that I had to use, I have downgraded Vagrant version to 1.8.5 by first uninstalling Vagrant and then installing the earlier version(1.8.5).

After that, Vagrant became unusable.

```
$ vagrant up
Bundler, the underlying system used to manage Vagrant plugins,
is reporting that a plugin or its dependency can't be found.
This is usually caused by manual tampering with the 'plugins.json'
file in the Vagrant home directory. To fix this error, please
remove that file and reinstall all your plugins using `vagrant
plugin install`.
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:356:in block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'vagrant-vbguest x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)`
```

After I run `vagrant plugin install` as suggested, I get the same error. The plugins.json doesn't contain anything relevant(C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\plugins.json):

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "installed": {
        "vagrant-share": {
            "ruby_version": "0",
            "vagrant_version": "1.8.5"
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed that I don't have ~/.vagrant.d directory. Does anyone know what is going on ? I tried reinstalling vagrant a couple of more times and it's the same error every time.

Answer (score 2):

I was going from Vagrant 2.0.0 to Vagrant 1.8.7, and ran into same issue.

I removed the file C:\Users\.vagrant.d\plugins.json.

Then ran the command: vagrant plugin install gems

This took care of the issue.

Comment: this, this, 1000 times this.